# how to reorder buttons on page refresh in a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, associative-array

Suppose I want to reorder the buttons in a form on page refresh such that when page refreshes, the buttons reoder their positions.
Well the main problem is that the text which I'm going to show in the buttons is from database data.
Below is the code which I'm trying now-

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


$res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
?>
<?php
    $array = array(
        '<?php echo $userRow['test1']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'foo', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test2']; ?>' => array( 'class' => 'john', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test3']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'x', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test4']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'a', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test5']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'b', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test6']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'c', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test7']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'd', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test8']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'e', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test9']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'f', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test10']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'g', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test11']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test12']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test13']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test14']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test15']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test16']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test17']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'idchange' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test18']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test19']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        '<?php echo $userRow['test20']; ?>'  => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
    );

    uksort( $array, function() { return rand() > rand(); } ); //This will mix them up.

    foreach( $array as $item => $atts ){
        <form action="check1.php" method="post">
        echo '<div class="'. $atts['class'] .'"><button name="'. $atts['name'] .'" type="submit" >'. $item .'</button></div>';
        </form>
    }
?>
```

so,its showing error..
so anyone who can help me in this problem?

Comment: As an immediate error I can see that here `$array = array( '<?php echo $userRow['test1'];` you have an open `<?php` tag and then opened another `<?php` tag without closing the first one. Please state which error you have, and the columns in users table.Also please check that you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you do not have an error in the database

```
<?
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    $res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    $array = array(
       $userRow['test1'] => array( 'class' => 'foo', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test2']=> array( 'class' => 'john', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test3'] => array( 'class' => 'x', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test4'] => array( 'class' => 'a', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test5'] => array( 'class' => 'b', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test6'] => array( 'class' => 'c', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test7'] => array( 'class' => 'd', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test8'] => array( 'class' => 'e', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test9'] => array( 'class' => 'f', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test10'] => array( 'class' => 'g', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test11'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test12'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test13'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test14'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test15'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test16'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test17'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'idchange' ),
        $userRow['test18'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test19'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
        $userRow['test20'] => array( 'class' => 'h', 'name' => 'update' ),
    );

    uksort( $array, function() { return rand() > rand(); } );

    foreach( $array as $item => $atts ){
        echo '<form action="check1.php" method="post">';
        echo '<div class="'. $atts['class'] .'"><button name="'. $atts['name'] .'" type="submit" >'. $item .'</button></div>';
        echo '</form>';
    }
?>
```